# Calculating number of transaction that occur in each month in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHf97.png)
I'm given a set of data transaction gathered throughout 3 years. I am required to count the number of transactions that occur each month and identify which month and year has more than 300 transactions.

I tried using this but idk how else I can do it.
Can you help me please?

The image attached has an example of the data I'm want to process

df[df[('Transaction_date')].value_counts()

Comment: Please  add your dataset columns or give an example of what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

**You need to further preprocessing your data so you can groupby `month` and `year` but you need to provide more information in question so my answer be specific for your question my answer is general so far**

```
    df['year'] = df['Transaction_date'].dt.year
    df['month'] = df['Transaction_date'].dt.month
    df.groupby(['year','month']).size()
```

Comment: So to be exact the company faces a 10p charge on each transaction if they exceed 300 transactions within a calendar month. I am required to identify the number of transactions the company has made per calendar month, alongside the value of any fees where appropriate.